# jquery multiple event responses

Tags: javascript, jquery, events

I am an experienced programmer, but don't have a lot of experience in Javacsript/JQuery.  I'm trying to fix someone else's code, so I'm a bit out of my comfort zone.  Plus, we are working with ancient versions of both.

We have dialog box that pops up from a link.  It has one text field and an OK button.  You type in an email address and information gets sent to you.  When you click OK, everything works as expected.  When you type enter after the address, you get n copies, n being the number of times the dialog box has opened.

```
  $(index_init);

  function index_init()
    {
    $("#forward_one_dialog").dialog(
      {
      autoOpen: false,
      modal: false,
      zIndex: 3000,
      buttons: { "Ok": forward_one}
      });
    $(".link_forward").click(function()
      {
      if ($("#forward_one_dialog").dialog("isOpen") == true)
      {
        return false;
      } else {
      $("#forward_one_dialog").dialog("open");
      $("#forward_one_dialog").keypress(function(e) {
        if(e.keyCode == $.ui.keyCode.ENTER) {
          forward_one();
        }
      });
      $("#forward_one_to").focus();
      }
    });
    }

  function forward_one()
    {
    var dialog = "#forward_one_dialog";
    var path = $("#forward_one_url").attr('value');
    var url = "/emails/list/" + path + "/forward/?fmt=json";
    var recipients = $("#forward_one_to").val();
    if (!recipients)
      {
      $(dialog).dialog("close");
      // this is in list.js:
      error_txt("#no_forward");
      return false;
      }
    var emailid = $("#forward_one_emailid").attr('value');
    var data = { "subset" : [emailid], "recipients" : recipients };
    $.post(
      url,
      data,
      function(jsonrpc, xhrstatus) {
        jsonrpc_status(jsonrpc, xhrstatus, "#forward_one_dialog");
      },
      "json"
     );
    $(dialog).dialog("close");
    return false;
  }
```

As you can see, forward_one is called when clicking OK and on enter.  It's just the number of times.

If it's any help, I tried resetting the value of the text field in forward_one.  In that case, the dialog box did not contain the last value.  I still got multiple calls, but only one had the new value.  The rest had the reset value.

Comment: Can you add the code for the `forward_one()` function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(".link_forward").click(function()
{
  /* ... */
  $("#forward_one_dialog").keypress(function(e) {
    if(e.keyCode == $.ui.keyCode.ENTER) {
      forward_one();
    }
  });
  /* ... */
});
```

You can see here that every time `.link_forward` is clicked, `keypress` is called.  This call to `keypress` **adds** a handler to the `#forward_one_dialog` element.  So each time it is clicked, another handler is added on top of the existing.  This is the cause of your issue.  Move this call to `keypress` outside of the click handler so that it is only applied once.  If it must be called only after opening the dialog, then create a boolean to track if it has already been called and ensure it is only called once.